# Unable to connect WSO2 API Manager to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, jdbc, wso2, mariadb, wso2-api-manager

I tried to change the WSO2 APIM default datastore from H2 to MariaDB.

I followed the instructons at: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-mysql/

I installed MariaDB on my system:

```
Server version: 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution
```

I created 2 databases:

```
mysql> create database WSO2_MARIA_DB;
mysql> create database APIM_DB;
```

I created the tables in the 2 databases:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -DWSO2_MARIA_DB < '<WSO2_HOME>/dbscripts/mysql.sql';
$ mysql -u root -p -DAPIM_DB < '<WSO2_HOME>/dbscripts/apimgt/mysql.sql';
```

I copied mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar and mariadb-java-client-2.6.0.jar java connectors to  /repository/components/lib

I changed the configuration in /repository/conf/deployment.toml to:

```
[database.apim_db]
type = "mariadb"
url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/APIM_DB"
username = "root"
password = "*********"
pool_options.maxActive = 50
pool_options.maxWait = 30000
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mariadb"
url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/WSO2_MARIA_DB"
username = "root"
password = "*********"
pool_options.maxActive = 100
pool_options.maxWait = 10000
pool_options.validationInterval = 10000
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

When I start the wso2server I get the following error:

```
ERROR - DatabaseUtil Database Error - Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@5d32515d[jdbc-pool:9.0.16.wso2v1(id=90)];

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Database Error - Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@5d32515d[jdbc-pool:9.0.16.wso2v1(id=90)];ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@6cb7db61
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:172) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:444) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@5d32515d[jdbc-pool:9.0.16.wso2v1(id=90)];ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@6cb7db61
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:292) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:162) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:444) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader@5d32515d[jdbc-pool:9.0.16.wso2v1(id=90)];ClassLoader:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder@6cb7db61
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:281) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:162) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:444) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.ContextFinder.loadClass(ContextFinder.java:139) ~[org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:281) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:198) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[jdbc-pool_9.0.16.wso2v1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.claim.dao.ClaimDAO.getDialectCount(ClaimDAO.java:162) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.populateProfileAndClaimMaps(DefaultRealm.java:444) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:126) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276) ~[org.wso2.carbon.user.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
```

Additional error log:

```
 Cannot create bundle from jar file /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/repository/components/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar
    java.io.IOException: Fail to create the directory: /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/tmp/jarsToBundles/15874636189820.989834824946039
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.util.Utils.createBundle(Utils.java:374)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.util.Utils.createBundle(Utils.java:356)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DefaultBundleCreator.perform(DefaultBundleCreator.java:68)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:152)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:104)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:70)


  SEVERE {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer updateBundlesInfoFile} - Failed to create the directory: /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/tmp/bundles_info_79a7e603-ed4a-49cc-be84-d9058b0cd29b/bundles.info 
    java.io.IOException: Failed to create the directory: /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/tmp/bundles_info_79a7e603-ed4a-49cc-be84-d9058b0cd29b/bundles.info
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.updateBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:353)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.perform(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:114)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:157)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:104)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:70)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)

    [2020-04-21 12:06:59,076]  SEVERE {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer perform} - Error occured while deploying bundles in the dropins directory 
    java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while updating the bundles.info file.
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.updateBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:375)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.perform(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:114)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.invokeExtensions(Main.java:157)
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:104)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:70)
            at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create the directory: /usr/lib/wso2/wso2am/3.0.0/tmp/bundles_info_79a7e603-ed4a-49cc-be84-d9058b0cd29b/bundles.info
            at org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer.updateBundlesInfoFile(DropinsBundleDeployer.java:353)
```

Here is my master-datasources.xml file from WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/datasources/

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">
<providers>
<provider>
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader
</provider>
</providers>
<datasources>
<datasource>
<name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
<description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
<jndiConfig>
<name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
</jndiConfig>
<definition type="RDBMS">
<configuration>
<url>
jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MVCC=TRUE
</url>
<username>wso2carbon</username>
<password>wso2carbon</password>
<driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
<maxActive>50</maxActive>
<maxWait>60000</maxWait>
<testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
<validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
<validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
<defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
</configuration>
</definition>
</datasource>
<datasource>
<name>WSO2_SHARED_DB</name>
<description>Shared Database for user and registry data</description>
<jndiConfig>
<name>jdbc/SHARED_DB</name>
</jndiConfig>
<definition type="RDBMS">
<configuration>
<url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/WSO2_MARIA_DB</url>
<username>root</username>
<password>*********</password>
<driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
<validationQuery/>
<testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
<maxWait>10000</maxWait>
<defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
<validationInterval>10000</validationInterval>
<maxActive>100</maxActive>
</configuration>
</definition>
</datasource>
<datasource>
<name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
<description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
<jndiConfig>
<name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
</jndiConfig>
<definition type="RDBMS">
<configuration>
<url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/APIM_DB</url>
<username>root</username>
<password>*********</password>
<driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
<validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
<validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
<testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
<defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
<maxActive>50</maxActive>
<maxWait>30000</maxWait>
</configuration>
</definition>
</datasource>
<datasource>
<name>WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</name>
<description>The datasource used for message broker database</description>
<jndiConfig>
<name>WSO2MBStoreDB</name>
</jndiConfig>
<definition type="RDBMS">
<configuration>
<url>
jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2MB_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000;MVCC=TRUE
</url>
<username>wso2carbon</username>
<password>wso2carbon</password>
<driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
<maxActive>50</maxActive>
<maxWait>60000</maxWait>
<testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
<validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
<validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
<defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
</configuration>
</definition>
</datasource>
</datasources>
</datasources-configuration>
```

What could have gone wrong?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's strange. Can you check if the `dropins` folder has the MySQL connector? If it's there, extract the jar and see if the Driver class is there.

Comment: I checked WSO2_HOME/repository/components/dropins folder and there are no java db connectors in it...

Comment: Are you sure you restarted the server after adding it to the lib?

Comment: Yes, but the server doesn't start... I am getting the following error: SEVERE {org.wso2.carbon.server.extensions.DropinsBundleDeployer perform} - Error occured while deploying bundles in the dropins directory 
java.lang.Exception: Error occurred while updating the bundles.info file.

Comment: I am running ./launcher_wso2server.sh as root

Comment: "Error occurred while updating the bundles.info file" this is the reason for the CNF error. Need to find why it can't update the file. Most probably permission issue in the file system.